# recorrer archivo json sin etiquetas

Tags: json

Hola tengo un serio problema, tengo un archivo json con el siguiente formato:

```
{
    "alberto": {
        "agis": "admin",
        "lima": "admin"
    },
    "pedro": {
        "agis": "admin"
    },
    "manu": {
        "lima": "admin"
    },
    "marcos": {
        "agisweb": "office"
    }
}
```

y no se como recorrerlo, estoy acostumbrado al típico formato:

```
{"poblacion":[ 
  { "id": "0", "nombre": "Alcobendas" }
  ,
  { "id": "1", "nombre": "Miraflores de la Sierra" }
  ,
  { "id": "2", "nombre": "San Fernando de Henares" }
]}
```

donde se puede recorrer como poblacion[0].nombre = Alcobendas etc.

Pero con la primera estructura estoy totalmente perdido, he conseguido recorrerlo metiendolo en un objeto donde le añado etiquetas para recorrerlo, pero necesito leerlo y modificarlo sin que la estructura del fichero inicial cambie y es ahí donde tengo el problema, alguien tiene idea de como recorrerlo?

me habían dicho algo como data['alberto'][agis] o algo así... pero nada lo he probado todo y no hay manera.

trabajo con angular 1.x por si hubiese algún método. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un for in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

```js
let list = { "alberto": { "agis": "admin", "lima": "admin" }, "pedro": { "agis": "admin" }, "manu": { "lima": "admin" }, "marcos": { "agisweb": "office" } };
    
    
    for (let key in list) {
        var element = list[key];
    
        list['alberto'].agis = 'Foo';
        
        console.log(key);
        console.log(element);   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes iterar sobre un objeto JS haciendo:

```
for (etiqueta in objeto) {
  console.log(etiqueta, objeto[etiqueta]);
}
```

Y si prefieres conocer de antemano las etiquetas del objeto:

```
var etiquetas = Object.keys(objeto);
console.log(etiquetas);
```

De manera que puedes iterar sobre el array `etiquetas` de la manera que te es familiar:

```
for(i=0; i<etiquetas.length; i++) {
  console.log(etiquetas[i], objeto[etiquetas[id]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para recorrer un objeto json puedes hacerlo con `Object.keys`. puede obtener el key y su respectivo value.

```js
var datos={ "alberto": { "agis": "admin", "lima": "admin" }, "pedro": { "agis": "admin" }, "manu": { "lima": "admin" }, "marcos": { "agisweb": "office" } };

Object.keys(datos).forEach(key => {
  let value = datos[key]
  console.log(key,value);
})
```